# db.load_only does not filter the fields

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, graphql, apollo

Suppose we have simple graphql-query:

```
 query EventQuery {
    event(id: 1) {
      id
      name
      description
  }
}
```

And our resolve method is something like this:

```
    def resolve_event(self, info, id):
        event = (Event.get_query(info).filter_by(id=id).options(db.load_only('id', 'name'))).first()
        return event
```

or

```
    def resolve_event(self, info, id):
        event = db.session.query(EventModel).filter_by(id=id).options(db.load_only('id', 'name')).first()
        return event
```

In both cases resolver will return id, name and description, db.load_only doesn't work at all. What have I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From the `load_only` documentation:

> Indicate that for a particular entity, only the given list of column-based attribute names should be loaded; all others will be deferred.

Here "deferred" means that the remaining columns will be lazy-loaded; so in your case, if anyone ever calls `event.description`, a separate SQL query will be emitted at that time to load the description column from the database.

The correct solution really depends on what you're dealing with at the next layer up: if you want your GraphQL queries to return SQLAlchemy entities that you can use in python, then the current behaviour is probably exactly what you want - just don't access `event.description` in your code. If you're instead building an API that returns JSON or similar, then the serialization layer also needs to be told which columns to extract from the `event` entity.